# What is the maximum frequency that can be captured by a given sampling rate?

Tags: audio, frequency, sampling

Let's say that we want to digitally sample an analog signal and have a sampling frequency of 8000 samples/second. Usually the maximum frequency that can be captured is the half of the sampling frequency; that is the maximum frequency that can be captured is approximately 4KHz for the example above. But what is the mathematical relationship between the two? 
Thank you.

Comment: It's a very common misconception that the sampling rate limits the maximum frequency when in fact it limits the bandwidth of the signal. An 8kHz sampling rate will allow you to reconstruct a signal with a bandwidth of 8kHz. Therefore, a real signal with a maximum frequency of 4kHz can always be reconstructed as a signal with a bandwidth of 8kHz, with frequencies ranging from -4kHz to +4kHz.

Comment: Do you know and understand the [sampling theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)? Because this should answer your question. Otherwise please formulate a more specific question.

Comment: it's small potatoes, but for a real signal being sampled, in fact the sampling frequency must **exceed** twice the maximum frequency.  it is not (even in theory) sufficient to sample a sinusoid at 4 kHz with a sample rate of 8 kHz (but, in theory, you **can** sample 3.99999 kHz sufficiently with 8 kHz sample rate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum frequency is also limited by how long you sample at a given sample rate.  If you only sample for a finite length of time at 8000 sps, the bandwidth will be **less than** 4kHz.  A 4000 Hz signal (or any integer multiple thereof) will be ambiguous, or simply disappear.

A signal somewhat below the Nyquist frequency (depending on how long you sample at a given S/N or accuracy) can be "captured", as well as any signals between two successive integer multiples of Fs/2 given a-priori knowledge of no aliasing from any other spectra inside any other folds.